# Have an item overlap the actionbar?

Tags: android

I am using the new `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` classes. I'm trying to have an image overlap the action bar. You can see in the screenshot that the actionbar is pulled down half of the screen and that the content view (an image in this case) overlaps it. Is this possible to do?

[image]

I've tried using a FrameLayout but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You have the answer in your xml layout. (FrameLayout) can do that

Comment: I've tried playing with a FrameLayout -- can't get it working. Can you show an example?

Comment: The FrameLayout should be the last thing you add in your android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and after android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout -- eg <FrameLayout><ImageView /></FrameLayout> -- also you shouldn't match parent but rather use dp and margin-top in + or - dp depending where you see the frame aligned

Comment: How is there going to be overlap if the FrameLayout is the last thing in the layout? I tried it -- but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you want to overlap something on-top of something else. this is were a framelayout comes in handy. its just a frame and can be moved any were on the screen and appear above something else. im using it and it works. But in your case it looks like the CoordinatorLayout is the problem so maybe a relative layout with a toolbar inside it and then the frame should work ok.  Not sure if it will work but what you can also do is put the CoordinatorLayout inside a framelayout and after the CoordinatorLayout  put another framelayout with that image. in theory that should work, but never tried it myself

Comment: Can you please show an answer? I've tried many layouts and all of them do not work.

Comment: forget the FrameLayout i mentioned as it did a test and it doesnt play well in a CoordinatorLayout.  However i had a thought and  created a FloatingActionButton  --  on a mobie its fully transparent but had some padding around the circle with a grey color i couldn't get rid off, so a custom rectangle shape of the FloatingActionButton   should be ok --  http://s12.postimg.org/ltkb0jaj1/Capture.jpg -- also give  (Android Dialog) a test as that  is always displayed on-top of anything and can have anything inside it and position where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have some familiarity with the **ToolBar** widget. You should consider replacing your **ActionBar** completely with a ToolBar. It will allow for overlapping and provide you with the same functionality as an ActionBar.

See here: http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: I actually have a ToolBar. I guess I need to call it an "app bar" now because that's the new name.

Comment: Yea I guess the actionBar is going to go away soon. It's not so flexible so I guess it makes sense.